# Cannot start a tcp based WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, tcp

I am developing a tcp base WCF service and I am getting this notorious WCF Exception while trying to launch the service in the host application:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
>
> Additional information: Service 'WcfServiceWas.MathService' has zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no service element matching the service name could be found in the configuration file, or because no endpoints were defined in the service element.

This problem was described many times before and the proposed solution is to name a service exactly as it is defined in the class library, the problem is this solution does not work for me.

What is wrong with the this configuration that the hosting service refuses to start the Service?

Service Interface (IMathService.cs):

```
namespace WcfServiceWas
{
   [ServiceContract]
   public interface IMathService
   {
      [OperationContract]
      OperationResult Add(int x, int y);

      [OperationContract]
      int Subtract(int x, int y);
    }
}
```

Service implementation (MathService.cs):

```
namespace WcfServiceWas
{
    public class MathService : IMathService
    {
        public OperationResult Add(int x, int y)
        {
            return new OperationResult { Result = new MyInteger { Value = x + y } };
        }

        public int Subtract(int x, int y)
        {
            return x - y;
        }
    }
}
```

Svc file (MathService.svc):

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WcfServiceWas.MathService" CodeBehind="MathService.cs" %>
```

Web.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfServiceWas.MathServiceBehavior" >
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
      <services>
        <service name="WcfServiceWas.MathService" behaviorConfiguration="WcfServiceWas.MathServiceBehavior" >
            <endpoint contract="WcfServiceWas.IMathService" binding="netTcpBinding" address="" />
            <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexTcpBinding" address="mex" />
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:999/MathServiceX/"/>
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
      </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Service host:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MathService)))
        {
            myServiceHost.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update: app.config of the hosting application has to contain wcf configuration as well.**

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your bindings section, under `<system.serviceModel>` add the below `<bindings>`  configurations :

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="netTcpBindingConfiguration" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

and edit the line `<endpoint contract="WcfServiceWas.IMathService"` to add the bindingconfiguration in it, as follows:

```
<endpoint contract="WcfServiceWas.IMathService"
          binding="netTcpBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="netTcpBindingConfiguration" 
          address="" />
```

Save these config changes and restart the service, it should work fine now.

**Update:**

so it appeared out that for self-hosting applications, configurations of WCF must be within the app.config of the host itself, and the  section is not a must to appear within the System.ServiceModel, since it will take default bindings , the msdn documentation illustrates this more

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee530014%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried to configure binding before (actually u dont have to have it according to documentation). And I tried your solution, did not do anything for me, unfortunately.

Comment: Look, I've created a new wcf service, and at first I got your exact error, then I moved the config section <system.serviceModel> from web.config of the WCF service to app.config of the service host, and it worked. Try this and let me know.

Comment: Changing app.config for the host app worked - so the configuration was ok it was just not taken into account. If u change your answer to that  I will accept it. Thanks.